# How does work about Enum == in dart, and how to override == for Enum

Tags: flutter, dart

```
enum TestElementLifecycle {
  oneone,
  twotwo
}
```

When I write below, how is it work in dart vm

```
if(TestElementLifecycle.oneone == 
  TestElementLifecycle.twotwo){
}
```

I have try add operate == in class Enum，but it seems not work at all
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7xIu.png)

I also look in object class, and also is empty
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Bnp.png)
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtXnE.png)

I am really refused how it is worked about == on enum？

If I want to override enum ==, what should I do?

Comment: What's your usecase for this?  All Enum classes already have a perfectly working == (and hashCode) that they inherit from Object, such that equality is derived from identity -- appropriate because enums are always const.

Comment: In order to use code push, we have modified flutter engine and dart vm.  Now everything is work well, except the enum compare always return false.   When I compare it's index or name, it work well.    So I want to override the operator == ....

Comment: Sounds like a bug that needs to be fixed in code push!

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a use case where you'd want two variants of the same enum to be equivalent...what am I missing here?

Comment: @JaredSmith It could be useful to create aliases.  For example, in other languages, I've made equivalent enumeration constants to rename a constant while preserving backward compatibility.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Enums and classes implementing `Enum` cannot have `index`, `hashCode`, and `operator==` overridden.

https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#illegal_concrete_enum_member

> The analyzer produces this diagnostic when either an enum declaration, a class that implements `Enum`, or a mixin with a superclass constraint of `Enum`, declares or inherits a concrete instance member named either `index`, `hashCode`, or `==`.